# Read a package NAMESPACE file

Tags: r

I am looking for a fast R solution to read a package `NAMESPACE` file. The solution should contain already preprocessed (and aggregated) records and separated imports and exports.

Unfortunately I *can’t* use `getNamespaceExports("dplyr")`/`getNamespaceImports("dplyr")` as they need the package to be loaded to the R session, which is too slow.

I need a solution which simply process a text from the `NAMESPACE` file. Any solutions using external packages as well as partial solutions would still be welcome.

The raw data we could grabbed with a call like `readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cran/dplyr/master/NAMESPACE")`. `roxygen2` generated files are formatted properly, but this will be not true for all manually generated files.

EDIT:

Thanks to Konrad R. answer I could develop such functionality in my new CRAN package - `pacs`. I recommended to check `pacs::pac_namespace` function. There is even one function which goes one step further, comparing NAMESPACE files between different package versions `pacs::pac_comapre_namespace`.

Comment: You can start with `readLines(system.file("NAMESPACE", package="dplyr"))`, but then you have other problems: (1) parsing out things like `export`, `S3method`, etc; and (2) dealing with asterisks such as `RCurl`'s `exportPattern("SSLVERSION_.*")`. While #1 may not be too difficult (perhaps write stub-functions for `export`, etc, and use `eval`/`parse`), #2 is not anywhere near as direct/easy and will ultimately require that you load the namespace anyway.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans. I should be more straight forward. I used github CRAN mirror instead of `system.file` because I want to analyze NAMESPACE files which are not installed locally. I not stressed that out as downloading a txt NAMESPACE file is not a problem. Still this  is showing that loading a package to the session will be hugely inefficient.

Comment: Ps. thanks for pointing out the regex * problem, which are rare nowadays. This case might be skipped for me as is not very popular now. Even one of my own R package with manual NAMESPACE file does not using * as I know this is a bad practice. I think most of other programmers do the same. Adding `roxygen2` popularity, this should be a minor case.

Comment: This is a problem for at least `RCurl`, `BH`, `acepack`, `e1071`, `fds`, `geosphere`, `gmp`, `gsubfn`, `hash`, `jpeg`, `mclust`, `mnormt`, `neural`, `png`, `qgam`, `raster`, and `sqldf`. Each of those packages (on a very quick and incomplete inspection) uses `exportPattern`.

Comment: SO I am building a new package which had to be tested an a whole R library , ~17500 packages. `sum(unlist(lapply(rownames(installed.packages()), function(x) any(grepl("exportPattern", readLines(system.file(package = x, "NAMESPACE")))))))` gives me 2950 packages on 17500. Where as If i run it on my second computer with only core packages I get a ratio 40 to 700. Ps. the package is already on CRAN https://github.com/Polkas/pacs.

Comment: Summing up even maximum 15% not available results is not a problem if I could retrieve 85% of the rest of them.

Comment: Interesting question and answer. I turn to using the 'pacs' package!  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is included in R as `base::parseNamespaceFile`. Unfortunately the function does not directly take a path as an argument. Instead it constructs the path from a package name and the library location. However, armed with this knowledge you should be able to call it; e.g.:

```
parseNamespaceFile('dplyr', .libPaths()[1L])
```

EDIT

Somebody has to remember that the whole packages imports (like `import(rlang)`) have to be still invoked with the same function and the exports for them extracted. Two core elements are using `parse` on NAMESPACE code and then using the recursive extract function `parseDirective`.

Comment: Great hint, thanks. I will research it's internals tomorrow.

Comment: I edited and accepted your answer:) Thanks once more.

Comment: @polkas Hmm, careful with this: R source code is GPL licensed, it may not be permissible to reproduce it verbatim here, where it’s implicitly licensed as CC BY-SA, which is not GPL compatible.